# Grid App - Images inside GridView not showing up

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm using the `Store App` -> `Grid App` template to make an app that reads data from the web and present the data in pages.

The data model I'm using is similar to (modification of) the default `SampleData.json` and `SampleDataSource.cs` provided with the template, except that I'm reading the data from two sources - one Group from an online xml file and the second Group from a time-intensive function.

I want the user to be able to open the first group (since it loads quickly) while the app loads the second group (which as I mentioned, takes time) and I'm using the following code to achieve this

```
private async Task GetGroups()
{
  SampleDataGroup group1 = new SampleDataGroup(/*initialization parameters*/);
  // add items to group1
  this.Groups.Add(group1);

  LoadGroup2(); // this async function is not awaited
}

private async Task LoadGroup2()
{
  SampleDataGroup group2 = new SampleDataGroup(/*initialization parameters */);
 // spend lots of time adding adding items to group2
 this.Groups.Add(group2);
}
```

This code works as expected (Group 1 is displayed, user can browse through the Group 1 items, 2 minutes pass and then Group 2 is loaded). My problem is that, at times (maybe 1 in 5 times, and for no reason that I can see) none of the images inside Group 2 (i.e. in the `GridView`) are loaded, i.e. they show up black. But clicking on any of the Group 2 items does take the user to the corresponding `ItemDetailPage.xaml`.

Why the apparently random lack of display of all the images in Group2 (inside the `GridView`)? Does it have to do with the async-await method I've used ?

Comment: Are the images too large in size? How long have you tried waiting for all of them to appear?

Comment: @bit No they're just about 250x250 and ~250kB..I've waited a long time - once it doesn't load at the beginning, it never loads at all.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803700/metro-ui-im-switching-xaml-but-images-not-loading